# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower' - Python

Tags: python, string, list

I am trying to convert the sentence into lower case with the below code

```
import re
temp =[]
snow = nltk.stem.SnowballStemmer('english')
for sentence in final_X:
    sentence = str(sentence.lower())                
    cleanr = re.compile('<.*?>')
    sentence = re.sub(cleanr, ' ', sentence)        
    sentence = re.sub(r'[?|!|\'|"|#]',r'',sentence)
    sentence = re.sub(r'[.|,|)|(|\|/]',r' ',sentence)        

    words = [snow.stem(word) for word in sentence.split() if word not in stopwords.words('english')]   # Stemming and removing stopwords
temp.append(words)
```

final_X = temp

---

I am getting the below error while executing the code

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-f0e602a068f6> in <module>()
      3 snow = nltk.stem.SnowballStemmer('english')
      4 for sentence in final_X:
----> 5     sentence = str(sentence.lower())
      6     cleanr = re.compile('<.*?>')
      7     sentence = re.sub(cleanr, ' ', sentence)

**AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'**
```

Comment: changing `str(sentence.lower())` to `str(sentence).lower()` will make the error go away. But you could possibly prefer `''.join(sentence).lower()` or a variation thereof.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to give you an exact fix as your post is not a reproduce-able error.  However the error message is pretty clear

`sentence` is of type `list` and has no method `lower`

One could imagine something like this

```
sentence = ['This', 'is', 'a', 'sentence']
```

If you want it in one string all lower case, you could do the following

```
' '.join(sentence).lower()
```

This will join all the strings in the list with a space into one string and then lowercase the result, yielding

```
'this is a sentence'
```

The caveat here is that based on your post I don't know what `sentence` looks like, just that it's a list